# How to remove files which are copied after running `make install`?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, shell

So the question is how am I supposed to uninstall or remove the files that has been installed after running the `make instal`? (Specially when I stop it in the middle of the process by a "Ctrl+C" or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `make clean` to delete the object files and executables created by make. it should delete the files that were partially built.

if the process was already copying compiled objects to other locations in your OS, you should try `make uninstall`. if that is not sufficient or not defined in your makefile, you may have to analyze your `Install:` section to determine what it does, and add the file locations  to the clean routine by editing the make file `clean:` function and including them in the commands therein.

See an annotated example of a makefile here, under 'A Simple Makefile'
http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html

If that answer is not sufficient, I recommend you post the makefile as part of your question.